# Missing data, MAR or MNAR?

Tags: missing-data

I have a dataset of car rentals by day from a car rental company. There are days for which the car rentals are zero, this largely, but not always, coincides with holiday days. Those days which are holidays and have rentals typically have lower rentals per day than non-holiday days.

So, if there are no rentals on some holiday days because they are holiday days (which typically have fewer rentals than non-holiday days) then is this data missing-at-random or missing-not-at-random? How might you deal with these observations?

Comment: This sounds like zero-inflated data, not missing data. What are you trying to study in this analysis?

Comment: Thank you, though the "zeroes" only account for around 3% of the data. I am trying to predict demand for car rentals. The zeroes have greater occurrence on holiday days.

Comment: If there are only ~3% zeros, then my initial thought is that including "holiday" as an independent variable in the model should be sufficient to model the increase in zeros. You shouldn't need to make any special adjustment for the zeros. What kind of model are you using? A poisson or negative binomial or something else?

Comment: Thanks David, I haven't settled on a model yet - I'm going to try a range. Would it matter that there is a variable "Off Day" that always has zero rentals? It just so happens that some of the "Off Days" are also holidays - but not always.

Comment: If you know that a certain variable is *always* associated with zero rentals, then you don't really need statistics for it. I would remove all of those days from the data and instead focus on modelling the rental rate on days that are "on". It will require a bit more bookkeeping if you estimate the average over a combination of "off" and "on" days (the average of "on" times the number of on days divided by the total number of days), but it should be more accurate to split out those off days and treat them separately. (1/2)

Comment: Unless you don't know in advance which days are "off" vs "on" and you need to model that. In that case I think you would want a zero-inflated model, where the "zero component" will be a model for the probability a day is an off day. (2/2)